# Convert string in JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, parsing, stringify

Hey I would like to transform this string into JSON:

```
var newPart = '{\'' + name + '\': {\'content-type\' : ' +  type + ', \'content\': ' + content +  ',\'type\': \'content\'}}';
```

The result gives the following string:

```
{'partHtml': {'content-type' : text/html, 'content': dfg,'type': 'content'}}
```

I would like to get a JSON object from this string, i tried the following but it fails with the error : **"SyntaxError: Unexpected token '"**

```
newPart = JSON.parse(newPart);
```

I tried without the ' with a few changes but the problem persists.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Change all single quotes to double.

Comment: all the strings must be quoted with double quotes

{
    "partHtml": {
        "content-type": "text/html",
        "content": "dfg",
        "type": "content"
    }
}

Comment: Your string does not represent JSON. See JSON specification at http://json.org

Answer (score 2):

Although Lorenzo's answer is correct, is there a reason why you are building the string like this? Why not just build the object to start with?

```
var type = 'text/html';
var content = 'dfg';
var name ='partHtml'

var newPart = {};
newPart[name] = {content_type: type, content: content, type: 'content'};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace this line with your

```
var newPart = '{\"' + name + '\": {\"content-type\" : \"' +  type + '\", \"content\": \"' + content +  '\",\"type\": \"content\"}}';
```

Comment: I did and same problem .. This is what i have now as a result but still the same problem: {'partHtml': {'content-type' : 'text/html', 'content' : 'fgh','type': 'content'}}

Answer (score 0):

JSON strings are quoted using `"`, not `'`.
Therefore, your example should be:

```
var newPart = '{"' + name + '": {"content-type" : ' +  type + ', "content": ' + content +  ',"type": "content"}}';
newPart = JSON.parse(newPart);
```

Or, if you already have everything you need, you could construct the object immediately without using `JSON.parse()`:

```
var newPart = {"name": {"content-type": type, "content": content, "type": "content"}};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a really bad practice and an unsafe method. You just need to create an object.

```
var newPart = {     
    "content-type" : "text/html",
    "content": "dfg",
    "type": "content"      
}
```

Comment: the object you're creating here is different than the one the OP needs. you left out the "partHtml" key.

Comment: Whatever this object looks like or contains, this is the most efficiency and safest method.

Comment: This is not an answer :)

Comment: Ok I missed the first key of the object. Please consider mikeecb's answer as the best one.

Comment: Yes, mikeecb's answer is correct, you'll probably want to remove this wrong one

Answer (score 0):

This is not a valid JSON, so it's not possible to parse it.
A valid version would look like this:

```
{"partHtml": {"content-type": "text/html", "content": "dfg", "type": "content"}}
```

You can't use the ' character, you need " instead.

Answer (score 0):

JSON strings are quoted using "

`var newStr = '{"' + name + '": {"content-type" : "' +  type + '", "content": "' + content +  '","type": "content"}}';

`var newJson = JSON.parse(newStr);`

or

`var newJson = eval('(' + newStr + ')');`

Answer (score 0):

you have to be careful while merging strings. Instead of creating a string and face delimitation problems i suggest to create an object instance and assign properties on the fly.

```
var newPart = {};
newPart.name = {content : content};
newPart.name['content-type'] = type;
```

and so on..

Answer (score -1):

There's an error in your JSON. `text/html` is a string, but it's missing quotes.

Try to add them:

```
var newPart = '{"' + name + '": {"content-type" : "' +  type + '", "content": "' + content +  '", "type": "content"}}'
```

Please notice that if you want a lint valid JSON, you should use double quotes. Test your JSON in any online tool such as http://jsonlint.com/

```
{
    "partHtml": {
        "content-type" : "text/html",
        "content": "dfg",
        "type": "content"
    }
}
```

Moreover, if your variables contain double quotes, you'll get an error while parsing the JSON. This answer would work for your code, but I don't recommend it in real applications because it's a bad practice. For the best practice, please look at the addition that mikeecb did to my answer.

Comment: I fixed in order to have quote everywhere like this : {'partHtml': {'content-type' : 'text/html', 'content' : 'fgh','type': 'content'}} but same error : SyntaxError: Unexpected token '

Comment: please check again, I edited the answer and added fixes directly to your code.

Comment: What if any of your variables contains double quotes ?

Comment: In this case you'll get an error while parsing. This answer would work for the OP's example code, but I don't recommend it in real applications because it's a bad practice. For the best practice, look at the addition that mikeecb did to my answer. Thanks for pointing it out, I,'ll update my answer